# Properly chrooting and unmounting on external USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, arm

I found multiple guides how to correctly chroot into an arm64 system. In my example I am working with the 21.10 Ubuntu arm image for raspbian pi. I am wondering what is the "best" and most complete way to do so? Or you using bind or rbind for /dev? When using rbind for dev, what is the correct way to unmount?

```
mkdir -p /mnt/usb

mount -o  /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
mount -o  /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb/boot/firmware

mount --bind /dev /mnt/usb/dev/
mount --bind /sys /mnt/usb/sys/
mount --bind /proc /mnt/usb/proc/
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/usb/dev/pts

# chroot to external system
chroot /mnt/usb /bin/bash

# Exit

# unmount mounts
umount /mnt/usb/{dev/pts,dev,sys,proc,boot,}
```

```
mount -o  /dev/sdb2 /mnt/usb
mount -o  /dev/sdb1 /mnt/usb/boot/firmware
mount -o rbind /dev /mnt/usb/dev
mount -t proc proc /mnt/usb/proc
mount -t sysfs sys /mnt/usb/sys
mount -o rbind /run/lvm      /mnt/usb/run/lvm
mount -o rbind /run/lock/lvm /mnt/usb/run/lock/lvm
chroot /mnt/usb /bin/bash

## Exit

umount /mnt/usb/run/lvm
umount /mnt/usb/run/lock/lvm
mount --make-rprivate usb/dev/pts
mount --make-rprivate usb/dev/
umount /mnt/usb/dev/pts
umount /mnt/usb/dev/
umount /mnt/usb/sys
umount /mnt/usb/proc
umount /mnt/usb/boot/firmware
umount /mnt/usb

exit
```

Findmnt for the second sequence:

```
├─/mnt/usb                   /dev/mapper/root ext4     rw,relatime,nodioread_nolock,nodelalloc
│ ├─/mnt/usb/boot/firmware   /dev/sdb1                 vfat       rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
│ ├─/mnt/usb/dev             udev                      devtmpfs   rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3952800k,nr_inodes=988200,mode=755,inode64
│ │ ├─/mnt/usb/dev/shm       tmpfs                     tmpfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,inode64
│ │ ├─/mnt/usb/dev/hugepages hugetlbfs                 hugetlbfs  rw,relatime,pagesize=2M
│ │ ├─/mnt/usb/dev/mqueue    mqueue                    mqueue     rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ │ └─/mnt/usb/dev/pts       devpts                    devpts     rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000
│ ├─/mnt/usb/proc            proc                      proc       rw,relatime
│ └─/mnt/usb/sys             sys                       sysfs      rw,relatime
´´´
```